# Does subsets of a semigroup with strictly smaller cardinality insure infinitely many disjoint translation copies of the set?

Tags: set-theory, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup with infinite cardinality, $A\subset S$ with $|A|<|S|$. Under what condition we may find a infinite net $\{s_\alpha; \alpha\in \Gamma\}$, such that $s_\alpha A \cap s_\beta A =\emptyset$ whenever $\alpha\neq \beta\in \Gamma$?

I know that this is insured when $S$ is a right cancellative semigroup. Then for each pair $B, C\subset S$ with $|B|, |C|<|S|$, there always exist $s\in S$, such that $B\cap sC=\emptyset$. Otherwise, for each pair of $s\neq t\in S$ would correspond with 2 different points in $B\times C$. Hence $|S|\le|B||C|$, which is impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite net?

Comment: @J.-E. Pin I mean a net actually which is a generalized notion of sequence. Sequence has to be countable, but net does not have to.

Comment: But since you do not mention any restriction on the cardinality of $\Gamma$ (other than being infinite), isn't it sufficient to find a sequence $s_n$ such that $n \not= m$ implies $s_nA \cap s_mA = \emptyset$ ? Or is $\Gamma$ part of the original data.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Pin Yes, it indeed is. I'm also curious if we can find uncountable many of left translations that satisfies this.